# How to get the Dependency calls in Application Insights using NodeJS Web application

Tags: node.js, azure, dependencies, azure-application-insights

I have developed a NodeJS web application, which I published it into azure web app and configured the application insights for that. Up to now every thing was working properly, one thing is when I go to application insights I am able to see only requests, events and exceptions but I am not getting any SQL dependency calls in AI, even though I am getting the data from Azure SQL Database.

I just followed the below link to configure the application insights for my NodeJS  web application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-nodejs

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above issue as soon as possible?

Comment: i'm not sure if sql azure dependencies are autocollected at this point.  you might want to post this as an issue on the node-js github repo?  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues